# How to initialize an added Class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a create account button, when I click that I call an ajax function and check if email already exists in database or not. It is working fine, but my front end developer has added a class ="next" in that button, so that I can go to the next part of the modal, just like gmail, swishing from left to right.

So, when I call the ajax function.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "{{ url('other/ajax-email-check') }}",
     data: {
         "email": $email,
         "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
     },
     success: function (data)
     {
         if(data.status == 1)
         {
             $('#registerModal .alert_text').append('<div class="col-md-12 alert alert-danger">Email is already registered</div>');
         }
         else
         {
             $('#registerModal .alert_text').addClass('next');
         }
     }
});
```

In the else area I am adding the next class which will bring in next modal, but when I am adding it is not working as it is not getting clicked. So, I want to initialize this 'next' class in the else area itself.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `addClass()` is exactly how you add a class to a set of matched elements.  When you observe the matched elements in the DOM, is the class being added?  Are you sure that selector is finding any elements in the first place?  Are you sure your `else` block is being executed?  What debugging have you done to confirm all this?  Currently you seem to be assuming that `addClass()` itself is broken and all of your code must be working.  That assumption is *probably* mistaken.

Comment: You need to do more debugging on your own, what lines have you stepped through? Please don't ask questions without doing due diligence and explaining exactly what you have tried, saying it doesn't work is not good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can fake click it right then and there:

`$('#registerModal .alert_text').addClass('next').click()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not triggering any click on the next class. The following might do the trick.

```
$('#registerModal .alert_text').addClass('next');
$("#registerModal").find(".next").trigger("click");
```